# How std::stack organizes internal storage?

Tags: c++, stack, std

How std::stack organizes storage under the covers, in what kind of structure it is allocates its storage? is it like a vector continues memory? or it is like list?

Comment: Which part of [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) leaves anything unclear to you?

Comment: @KerrekSB there were unclear parts which guys covered by their answers, thanks for comment and wanting to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses data structure that is passed as second template argument, `std::deque` by default.

You may pass any Container class such that it satisfy these requirements:

> The type of the underlying container to use to store the elements. The container must satisfy the requirements of **SequenceContainer**. Additionally, it must provide the following functions with the usual semantics:
>
> - back()
> - push_back()
> - pop_back()
>
> The standard containers `std::vector`, `std::deque` and `std::list satisfy` these requirements.

[Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)

Answer (score 3):

[stack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) is container-adapter. It can work on any container, which will be pointed in template parameter, default is `std::deque`.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/) clearly has the answer to it:

> stacks are implemented as containers adaptors, which are classes that
>   use an encapsulated object of a specific container class as its
>   underlying container, providing a specific set of member functions to
>   access its elements.
>
> .........................
>
> The standard container classes vector, deque and list fulfill these
>   requirements. By default, if no container class is specified for a
>   particular stack class instantiation, the standard container **deque** is
>   used.